# Putting the pieces together - Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-alarms

I had created some code to check on functionality, based on the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258161/setting-up-a-service-via-alarm-manager-in-android)

After invoking the Service with the help of an alarm manager, I have a question.

I want to put this code in the splash screen of my app, however am uncertain on the behaviour if the code of Alarm manager is put inside onCreate. I suspect that each time my application starts a new alarm will be added at a specified time.

Do I need to run this code only once or will it be fine to put it in the onCreate of the splash screen?

Comment: then put that in onClick of a button !

Comment: The process needs to be automated, I could have thought of putting it inside a button click but that is not what I intend to ask in the question.